# PHP Count Images Search Results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search results page which displays items from a MySQL database (table1). The code I am using to the display the results is:

```
if (!empty($data)) {
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        echo '<div class="item">';
        if (strlen($item['item_desc']) > 10) {
            if (strlen($item['item_link']) > 10) {
                echo '<a href="/item.php?id='.$item['item_id'].'">';
            } else {
                echo 'No Results Found';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The images for each search result are stored in a separate table (table2). I am trying to use the code below to count the number of images in table2 for each result and display the number against each result on the search results page, but it returns a 0 value?

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from table2 where id = '" .$item['item_id']. "'");
$query=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $query['total'];
```

Comment: Is `$item['item_id'];` have results?

Comment: Yes this displays the ID which is needed for the count

Comment: Can i see your table structure?

Comment: Table1: id, item_id, item_link, item_desc and Table2: id, item_id, image

Comment: Is item_id from table1 is equal to the item_id of table2?

Comment: So your query should be: `"SELECT count (*) from table2 where item_id =".$item['item_id'];`

Comment: Sorry yes this is what I have tried but it still doesn't display. Is the 'as total' not required?

Comment: Can i see the first data of both tables?

Comment: Table1: ID = 1, item_id = 101 | ID = 2, item_id = 102. Table2: ID = 1, item_id = 101, image = 1.jpg | ID = 2, item_id = 101, image = 2.jpg

Comment: `"SELECT count (*) as total from table2 where item_id =".$item['item_id'];` can you try this again? when you do can you please do this `print_r($result)`

Comment: Nothing is printed when using that code?

Comment: `SELECT count (*) as total from table2 where item_id = '101'` try this. Surely this will show output.

Comment: Do you want to count only in your query?

Comment: Got this working now, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am missing some data about your database structure but I can imagine you store your image id as an integer and you are requesting the count with the id being a string.

So, if I'm true this may help. Remove the quotes around the php variable with the item_id

`"SELECT count(*) as total from table2 where id = " .$item['item_id'];`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this..

```
$str=$item['item_id'];
mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from table2 where id = '$str'");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mysql function to count rows outputted from your mysql query, it is **mysql_num_rows()**. From what I can understand about your database your code could be this:

```
$item_id = $item['item_id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 where id = '$item_id'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $count;
```

This will output how many records match your query.